# ASP.NET GridView - Control Moves around in Content Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview, master-pages

I've got a project that uses a Master Page.

There is also a Content Page that displays the summary of my data in a GridView control.

The basics of this content element are:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Search: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColum" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
    <td>Value: <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td><asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"></asp:Button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <asp:GridView ID="summaryGrid" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried adding CSS to the `table`, to the `table row`, to the `table detail`, to the `asp:GridView` and to the *GridView* control's `CssClass`.

No matter what I do, as soon as the data is bound to the *GridView* control, the control will completely fill the `<table>`, hiding my search controls in the first row.

After reading up on numerous other related problems online, I thought it might be because my control does its databinding in the code behind. Therefore, I redesigned my ASP.NET page to bind in the HTML. The problem is still there, I just no longer get to initially see my search controls in the first row.

Does anyone familiar with what would cause something like this?

**EDIT:**

By popular request (1 person), here's the link to the project: [>> LINK <<](http://sites.google.com/site/jp2code/home/list/AcpSheetMetal.zip) (All binary information has been removed)

Note, however, that the data binding features will not work on your end.

Comment: Can you limit the amount of data being bound for debug purposes? Do you get the same result when binding only a few rows? Have a look at the page with issues in Firefox with Firebug that should also help point you in the direction of the problem. I would also move away from a table based layout for your controls.

Comment: send the resulting html to a validator and see if you have a tag mismatch, also open in developer tools mode and look at the DOM directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jp: I have reproduced your problem with a Master Page-->Content Page-->the same Table you have above and it does not create this problem.  Please copy your CSS in.

Edit, offending lines in your CSS are:

```
div {
   left: 0px;
   position:absolute;
   top: 0px;
   width:100%;
   z-index:0;
}
```

So, you're telling all Divs to be position absolutely at the top left.

Comment: See **EDIT** with code link. All code is better than posting something that might not help.

Comment: Thanks.  I've confirmed the CSS is causing the problem. See edits.

Comment: I'm so glad I posted the entire solution. If I'd posted code that I thought was related, I never would have posted that!

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing an example of the HTML as rendered it is hard to tell what is breaking the layout.

I'd move away from a table based design for the search controls to something like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="search">
        <label>Search: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColum" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></label>
        <label>Value: <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></label>
        <span><asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"></asp:Button></span>
    </div>
    <asp:GridView ID="summaryGrid" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

With the following CSS styles:

```
.search
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#F00;        
    padding:2px;
}


.search label, .search span
{
    width:32%;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:inline-block;
}

.container table
{
   width:100%;
}
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bX2mL/4/) gives you an idea of how it should work

Adding the label tags also gets you a more accessible form.

**Edit**
In response to your comment, and if you get the table enforced upon you from above (I've had that happen), don't nest the tables.

```
<div class="container">
   <table>
    <!-- Search Control Stuff -->
   </table>
   <asp:GridView ID="summaryGrid" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Setting the widths of the search table and gridview table by CSS as appropriate

Also here is a [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bX2mL/5/) showing how to do this with the semantically better option of the [fieldset](http://www.html-tags-guide.com/html-fieldset-tag.html) tag

I've also tweaked the width of the labels and spans

Comment: LOL - and my manager said to just put it in a table because the CSS would take too long. Let me look into that...

Answer (score 1):

Try it without css. Also, GridView renders html table itself, so it may cause this problem. Always check what is in generated html, not what you see. It always provide quick answer if it is code issue or just css is not correct, hiding some element, height not correct etc

Comment: ...and it creates a lot of HTML! Edited my question to include link to code sample.